# I get keep getting 'Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.' error with jetpack compose ui testing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to write ui test with compose. And I get `Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.` error. Is there any solution? here's my test code.

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class VitaminScreenComposeTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun entryQuestionLayout(){
        val entryQuestionJson = loadFileText(this, "/surveyQuestion.json")
        val entryQuestion = Gson().fromJsonToArrayList(entryQuestionJson, Question::class.java)[0]

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            VitaminScreen(false, entryQuestion, {},{},{})
        }

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("scientific").assertIsDisplayed()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("professional").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```